# Musicnotes importing PDF files

Tags: software

Am I right in thinking one can't import PDF files from cloud sites like iCloud into Musicnotes?

Comment: I would recommend you to edit your post, especially the title, I don't think this way of asking is going to get very warm feedback from the community... I can do that for you but you have to accept it.

Comment: @nath that edit pushes it more towards a shopping question.  As it stands now, it looks to me like a "usage of music specific software", specifically Musicnotes, question.

Comment: @Dave fair enough, I see your point. Doms edit is much clearer anyway! I think I also got the question wrong, so I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 3):

What exactly do you want to do with the pdf file?  The problem here is that "PDF" is a container, not a specific format.  The file could contain nothing but bitmapped images.  If you just want to drop images into your score (in MusicNotes), and images are supported, then that can be done.

Just because you see text, or sheet music, in a PDF document doesn't mean that there's processable text characters.  Even if there are, PDF does really strange things in its page layout, and very few applications are capable of importing without fouling up the layout.

BTW,  "iCloud" is just a data storage site, as are all other so-called "cloud" sites.  The location of the servers has nothing whatsoever to do with the file formats.

So, with those software caveats,  why not surf on over to [their blog](http://www.musicnotes.com/blog/2016/04/18/musicnotes-player-app/) to discover that, yes,  at least for certain sheet music PDFs,  MusicNotes is perfectly happy to import the files.